# Battery fails to calibrate

Tags: laptop, battery, power

Some time ago I bought an aftermarket extended battery for my laptop (HP Probook 4540s). First things first I tried to properly calibrate it — full charge and then discharge. However when the counter showed around 30% computer suddenly powered off with a "critical low power" message. When I plugged it in and powered it on, battery wouldn't charge. I left it plugged for around 24h and only then it began to charge. I didn't do any more calibration attempts after that afraid that it would kill it and just kept the computer plugged in at all times.

Some time afterwards, I was using computer on the battery power again. I had no intention to drain it completely, but the same thing happened — when the estimate showed I still had an hour of power left, it shut down and (7h online so far) battery is not charging. Is the battery faulty?

[image: battery dischagre graph].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've purchased an "aftermarket" battery, the battery is either faulty or it has been marketed falsely. Some batteries are often marketed higher than their actual ratings, such as 10000mAh LiPo batteries - these batteries are usually around 1200mAh despite being sold as 10000mAh batteries.
In either case, your battery is probably suspect - even more so being 'aftermarket'